# Scala in IDEA: Do I have to add Akka explicitly?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka, actor

I started off with a IDEA Java project, packed by Gradle (plugin: 'java').

Later on I applied `plugin: 'scala'` and added `compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1'` as dependency.

Now I would like to use Akka, and to my understanding it should be shipped with Scala automatically but I cannot import any Akka class.

I just checked the distribution from *akka.io* and realized that there Akka is shipped with Scala and not the other way round.

Am I doing anything wrong? Were my assumptions (basically: Akka is an integral part of Scala and shipped along automatically) or do I have to add Akka manually to my project?

Comment: No, Akka is a separate library. Not part of Scala.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Is there a Gradle (Maven Central) dependency I can add?

Comment: The group is `com.typesafe.akka`. The core artifact is `akka-actor`. ([search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Acom.typesafe.akka%20a%3A%22akka-actor_2.11%22))

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thanks a lot, that works! One more question: Does it contain as well Scala and Java implementation?

Comment: I've never used Akka with Java, but the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/intro/getting-started.html) seem to suggest that any of the Scala builds will work for Java as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Akka is a separate library. Not part of Scala.

It's on Maven Central under the group `com.typesafe.akka`. The core artifact is `akka-actor`. ([search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Acom.typesafe.akka%20a%3A%22akka-actor_2.11%22))

I've never used Akka with Java, but the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.6/intro/getting-started.html) seem to suggest that any of the Scala builds will work for Java as well.